# JS: Difference in effect of how private functions are declared

Tags: javascript, function, private

In this JS snippet, I have an object with two versions of a private function (bar and bar2). I declare two instances, but I was caught out by the fact that one version of the private function (bar) seems to be wrongly accessing the value of the private var v in the OTHER object. Can anybody please tell me why this is?

```
Eric = function(_v)
{
    var v = _v;

    bar = function() {
        alert(v);
    };

    function bar2() {
        alert(v);
    };

    this.foo = function() {
        bar();
    };

    this.foo2 = function() {
        bar2();
    };
};

var e = new Eric('I am Eric');
var e2 = new Eric('I am Eric II');

e2.foo();   // outputs "I am Eric II"
e.foo();    // outputs "I am Eric II" ------ WHY?

e2.foo2();  // outputs "I am Eric II"
e.foo2();   // outputs "I am Eric"
```

Many thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bar = function() {
    alert(v);
};
```

You've made `bar` global. This means that `bar` is the second bar function defined in your call `e2 = new Eric("I am Eric II");`

Fix this by using `var bar = ...` to make it local.

As a seperate note you forgot `var Eric`.

You also do not need to locally declare `var v` since you the constructor argument `_v` is in scope. You can just continue using that argument instead.

Comment: Ah, I see! I had wrongly assumed that, since bar was declared inside Eric, it was local. Thanks, Raynos, for clearing that up (and my other errors! :-) )

Comment: Mind you, I'm still slightly puzzled as to why, since bar is global, it has access to the private variable v.

Comment: @andrewk your creating a local function. And then making a global pointer to that local function. This means the function has access to your locally scoped `v` but you have access to that function globally. There is no such thing as `private`. There are only local variables.

Comment: `bar()` isn't declared, that's why it becomes global when `Eric()` (which isn't declared either) is first called. `bar()` has a reference to `v` as a closure because it's *initialised* inside `Eric()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because bar is being redefined on the object with the second call. If you switched to this it should work:

```
this.bar = function() {}
```

Of course, that breaks the private function you want. `bar` is not a symbol local to just your Eric instance.